# Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density. Find $P(x\leq 2/3\mid x\geq 1/3)$.

Tags: probability

> Let 
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> 4x^3, & 0< x\leq 1\\
> 0,&\text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}$$
>   Find $P(x\leq 2/3\mid x\geq 1/3)$.

Can someone explain this through. I know that I just need to perform integration on $4x^3$ then substitute the given values but I've never encountered this problem with a sign like this"|" this is a conditional probability right? like $A|B$ like $A$ occur given $B$. But in this problem how it work?

Comment: Please review the edit so you can learn some more formatting. Use `$a\leq b$` to show $a\leq b$. Extra tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It probably stands for "given" , since if it were an "or",  then I see the problem becoming very easy. It certainly could be an and as well. As an exercise for yourself, solve the and case as well as the given case. Then you get the best benefit of the problem, right?

Comment: @abd It was given that $x\geq 1/3$ not $x\leq 1/3$.

Comment: Consider giving [check marks](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to respondents.

Comment: exactly right? if it were a mathematical or, then it would be true for all x, so the probability would be 1. That's what I meant. If it were an and, then it would stand for the interval $[1/3,2/3]$. Feel free to point out further mistakes, I'm only just on the job.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that means conditional probability and in order to solve it you thus use the equation $$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$ where in this case you have $A,B$ are the events that $x\leq 2/3, x\geq 1/3$, respectively. You can thus say that $$P(x\leq 2/3\mid x \geq 1/3)=\frac{P(x\in[1/3,2/3])}{P(x\geq 1/3)}$$ and from here I'll assume you can solve by integration?

Comment: what would be my upper limit and lower limit?

Comment: When you're integrating you have that $P(a<x<b)=\int_a^b f(x)dx$ so try applying that to this problem.

Comment: You mean my lower limit is $\frac{2}{3}$ and upper limit is $\frac{1}{3}$? but i thought upper limit should be higher?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget what you have learned to this point. Just use Bayes' rule! :)

$$P(x\leq 2/3\mid x\geq 1/3) = \frac{P(x\leq 2/3,x\geq 1/3)}{P(x\geq 1/3)} = \frac{P(1/3\leq x\leq 2/3)}{P(1/3\leq x)}$$
and compute as usual.

Comment: wait I'm confused so before I perform my integration the value of my X would be?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You compute the last expression using integration, like usual.

Comment: I mean what would be my upper limit and lower limit?

Comment: What makes me confuse is if my upper limit is $\frac{2}{3}$ and lower limit is $\frac{1}{3}$ if this are my limits, then why did it still said in a conditional probability manner?

Comment: Because you are told that $x\geq 1/3$, so your outcome space reduces from the interval $(0,1]$, to $[1/3, 1]$. That is what happens when you use conditional probability.

Comment: @Rajesh $\dfrac{\mathsf P(1/3\leq X\leq 2/3)}{\mathsf P(1/3\leq X)}=\dfrac{\displaystyle \int_{1/3}^{2/3} f_X(x)\operatorname d x}{\displaystyle \int_{1/3}^{1} f_X(x)\operatorname d x}$